# Runing website using ng serve on ec2 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am working with this  [git project](https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter) and can't get the website to work on my server. On my mac everything works fine.

I dont get any errors other than I can't access it.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks,

Stephen

Comment: you need open the `console` or `network` of your browser to see whether there are errors and paste these error to let others help you.

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: I am running a ubuntu 16.04 server. The package.json file runs both the node server and the frontend. I can access the node server on port 4300 but cannot access the application server on port 4200.

Comment: @XinMeng there are no errors other than "This site can’t be reached" for port 4200. I have no issues with the node server on port 4300

Comment: check the port on your server:  `sudo netstat -nlp | grep 4200` to see is there any unnormal processes

Comment: @XinMeng just checked nothing running on it when server is stopped.

Comment: Maybe you could check the different between two port:1: run with 4300, use the cmd to see the process of 4300. 2: run with 4200, use the cmd to see the process of 4200. and compare them to see is there any difference.

Comment: by the way, whether your firewall is enabled?

Comment: @XinMeng no difference, have completely disabled my aws firewall until i get this sorted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144368/discussion-between-xin-meng-and-stephen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, had to deploy and run using pm2. npm run build creates a dist folder which contains server and client folders.

Answer (score 0):

Hit `npm start` in the project directory.
The script associated is declared in the `package.json` under `scripts [...]`

Comment: Yes, i can see that. When I run this i can access my node server via  port 4300. However, I cannot access port 4200 which is server the angular files. This is the bit im struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit : After Looking into your project**
Try to rename **.angular-cli.json** to **angular-cli.json**

---

There are many possibilities of this behavior:

1. Relevant bundler is not installed
2. angular-cli.json is not present
3. angular cli is not initialized

---

Steps to initialize Angular CLI

1. npm install
2. npm install angular-cli
3. ng init (with in project directory)

Please first understand how ng serve works and what is happening behind the scene. In this way you will be able to resolve the dependencies .